# X not have valid feature names, reshape warning, X is 2D, Ya is 1D

Tags: python, arrays, linear-regression

**PROBLEM**
Issue is not valid names in X features: "UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted with feature names"

X is 2D, Ya is 1D response variable.

And ValueError on

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[445], line 5
      3 lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
      4 lm.fit(X, Ya)
----> 5 res = lm.predict(Ya)
...
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.24107763 0.20358284 0.26190807 ... 0.321622   0.14890293 0.15636717].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

**CODE for linear model**

This code executes with ValueError

```
from sklearn import linear_model
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X, Ya)
res = lm.predict(Ya)
```

**CODE SHAPE for Y response variables with reshape(-1,1)**

This code runs before LinearRegression

```
Y = train_data['SalePrice']
X = train_data.drop(['Id'], axis=1).values

Ya = Y.values
Ya.reshape(-1, 1)
print('Y shape:', Ya.shape)
Ya.head
```

**Data and object shape**

```
Y shape: (1460,)
array([0.24107763, 0.20358284, 0.26190807, ..., 0.321622  , 0.14890293,
       0.15636717])
```

**CODE SHAPE for X features**

```
print('X shape:', X.shape)
X
```

**Data**

```
array([[0.15068493, 0.0334198 , 0.66666667, ..., 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.20205479, 0.03879502, 0.55555556, ..., 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.1609589 , 0.04650728, 0.66666667, ..., 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        ],
       ...,
       [0.15410959, 0.03618687, 0.66666667, ..., 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.1609589 , 0.03934189, 0.44444444, ..., 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.18493151, 0.04037019, 0.44444444, ..., 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        ]])
```

Original train_data values

```
LotFrontage LotArea OverallQual OverallCond YearBuilt   YearRemodAdd    MasVnrArea  ExterQual   ExterCond   BsmtQual    ... SaleType_ConLw  SaleType_New    SaleType_Oth    SaleType_WD SaleCondition_Abnorml   SaleCondition_AdjLand   SaleCondition_Alloca    SaleCondition_Family    SaleCondition_Normal    SaleCondition_Partial
0   0.150685    0.033420    0.666667    0.500   0.949275    0.883333    0.12250 0.666667    0.5 0.8 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
1   0.202055    0.038795    0.555556    0.875   0.753623    0.433333    0.00000 0.333333    0.5 0.8 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
2   0.160959    0.046507    0.666667    0.500   0.934783    0.866667    0.10125 0.666667    0.5 0.8 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
3   0.133562    0.038561    0.666667    0.500   0.311594    0.333333    0.00000 0.333333    0.5 0.6 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   0.215753    0.060576    0.777778    0.500   0.927536    0.833333    0.21875 0.666667    0.5 0.8 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
5 rows × 249 columns
```

Comment: `Ya.reshape(-1, 1)` is a void statement. You probably meant `Ya=Ya.reshape(-1, 1)`. Or `Ya = train_data[['SalePrice']].values`. Note that `df[col]` is a series, so a 1d array. `df[[col]]` is a dataframe, a 2D-array, even with only one column (`df[[col1, col2, ...]]` extract some chosen columns). So `train_data['SalePrice'].values` is 1D and needs reshape. `train_data[['SalePrice']].values` is 2D and doesn't. `LinearRegression` expect `Y` to be a set of columns to explain (maybe only one), from another set of columns, `X`

Comment: yes, I really forgot to put ().value for numpy array

Comment: after executing ().value, my shape on X is 365000 and Y is 1460; then error is "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [365000, 1460]"

Comment: My point was not about `.values`. I didn't notice that one is missing. It was about how to get the correct shape. From a dataframe, by using double bracket (that is indexing a dataframe with a list of columns), instead of a single one. Or, from a 1D ndarray, to reshape, by taking into account `.reshape` being not a "in place" method, but something that returns a new, reshaped, array.

Comment: chrsig: thanks for the insight on reshape and arrays... I was away on many calls for interviews.